# How to create RESTful CRUD operations typed web services using Native XML-databases?

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, jdbc, nativexml

I have to create a RESTful webapplication/Web service which performs CRUD operations where I have to use XML Native databases(eXist,BaseX).

Can anybody help me to how to make a Native Xml database connection with netbeans/eclipes or anyother IDE?

Is there any specific JDBC/ODBC driver or method to connect such XML databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to eXist then you need to place a conf.xml in the app server to help setting up the connection.

[This](http://exist.sourceforge.net/configuration.html) config page helped me to setUp the DB. And also for editor i was on Vim and eXist even gives you debugger support for Vim.